# How to Assert an Obscured XCUIElement is Not Hittable on Screen with Xcode UI Testing

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

I hope I can clearly explain what I'm about to ask -- please be patient with me if the clarity isn't there yet.

I'm encountering a snag with UI Testing when it comes to views in the view hierarchy that are "hidden" behind other top-facing views. I know `XCUIElement` objects have the `exists` and `isHittable` interfaces that we can leverage, but these interfaces are not helping me in my trying to assert that an element is not hittable when it's obscured behind a view that's blocking it from sight.

Anybody have insight in how to properly assert this?

Comment: Are you using XCUIAutomation or Xcode UI Testing? XCUIAutomation is written in JavaScript while Xcode UI Testing is written in Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: Hmm..maybe I'm getting the wrong impression of terms? My impression was the reverse of what you stated -- where the `XCUI` namespace APIs (e.g `XCUIApplication`) are the ones that come bundled with Xcode 7 (hence the `XC` that's part of the namespace prefix). That's the one I'm speaking to in my question. A clarification of terms may be needed here for me, haha.

Comment: Actually, I mislabeled the first term. UI Automation doesn't have the `XC` in front of it! Here's are [two](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7) [posts](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet) I wrote to get you started on Xcode UI Testing.

Comment: Funny you should be the one answering me and bringing up those posts Joe -- I actually read them already, haha! And before anything I want to say you have some really fantastic content and information on there. Cannot thank you enough for writing them out. Unfortunately, none of what I saw on your posts seem to address or speak to my particular situation. Or maybe I've read some of your content wrong. Basically, I have a view "hidden" behind another view and I'm trying to assert that view is not hittable in a given state but none of the `XCUI` interfaces are helping me to correctly assert that

Comment: Thanks! I understand your question now, I'll answer below to end this string of meta comments.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the unfortunate answer is "You can't". XCUITest doesn't have a way to tell you if something is rendered visibly on the screen (or that something is in the UI View's foreground). You can, however, set `userInteractionEnabled` to false for the element itself when a view is drawn over it or otherwise have your app code signify that it is not intended for the user to access it; your code can then assert that the element is not `enabled`.

This could have the positive side effect of eliminating race conditions where you interact with a button while the view that would hide it is being drawn over it.

You can also simply assert the existence of the element that is obscuring the element you're asserting is obscured, or you can optionally use CGRect's logic to assert that the UI View being drawn over your hopefully-no-longer-visible UI element fully obscures it.

Answer (score 1):

One weird behavior of `exists()` is that it returns `true` even if the element is off the screen. You have to jump through some hoops to make sure the element is actually visible to the user.

To test that an element is actually on screen we can assert that the element's frame is contained in the window's frame.

```swift
    let window = app.windows.element(boundBy: 0)
    let element = app.buttons["On"]
    XCTAssert(window.frame.contains(element.frame))
```

Comment: I tried this very same solution and it did not return the results I expected unfortunately :(

But hold that thought, for some reason an idea just popped into my head as you typed this out. Maybe I need to narrow my scope. Instead of grabbing the whole window, what I need to do is maybe grab the top-most view and just assert that my "hidden" button isn't on that view's rect... The plot thickens... Gonna try and see what this does.

Comment: I see. You will need to post more of your code to help better debug what's going on.

Comment: @JoeMasilotti does this have a good Objective-C equivalent? I keep getting  "property 'frame' not found on object of type 'XCUIElement *'". Here's an example (sorry I can't get it to format):

    `- (BOOL)itemInView:(XCUIElement *)item
    {
     XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
     XCUIElement *window = [app.windows elementBoundByIndex:0];
     return CGRectContainsRect(window.rect, item.rect);
    }`

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I just read your Twitter post about this and saw that isHittable now returns the correct value. Here is what I am going to assume is the correct Objective-C equivalent as of XCode 7.1:

`- (BOOL)itemInView:(XCUIElement *)item
{
 return item.isHittable;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I would use hittable() to ensure it is actionable

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. The problem with this is that `hittable()` (Swift) or `isHittable` (ObjC) returns true even though an element is obscured behind another view. In reality, when you interact with this element on screen, as a user, you would not be able to hit the element because the top facing view would be blocking your touch so it should not be considered "hittable".